# CraftCMS: Search entries by title in CMS

Tags: search

In the CraftCMS admin page at `/admin/entries/`, there is a search bar at the top:

[image: Search bar in CMS]

This search bar appears to only search the `Body` field of Entries.

**Is it possible to make this search bar match against the `Title` field too?**

Eg. I have an Entry titled "Example Entry" with a body of "Testing 1 2 3". If I search for "Testing", my Entry will show in the search results. If I search for "Example", my Entry will not show. I would like my Entry to show for the search term "Example"

Answer (score 1):

It does search for the title by default.

I'm assuming you're on MySQL for the database. The `searchindex` table uses the MyISAM storage engine by default and `example` happens to be of the default MySQL MyISAM stopwords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html (see "Stopwords for MyISAM Search Indexes"), which it will skip.